# Ideas how to Pivot in Excel 2013

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013

currently have this data the i need to display in a pivot table. losing my mind where to drag those columns in order to achieve the expected output.

If not possible could you recommend other ways to pivot them in a way that is much more understandable.
[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNV1j.png)
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY6gZ.png)